# prevent component from unmounting when displayed in different parts of the DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

The layout of my app changes depending on some choices made by the user so the same component gets hung under different nodes in the DOM. Unfortunately, React unmounts and re-mounts the component. As a result, my component loses the state is has accumulated. I have tried to add a `key` property to convey the information that this is the same instance but I got the same results. The below is obviously a SSCCE. Every time the user clicks the button, component `A` gets unmounted and re-mounted:

```
class A extends React.Component {
  componentWillUnmount = () => {
    console.log('map::componentWillUnmount()');
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    console.log('map::componentDidMount()');
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        this is component A
      </div>
    );

  }
}


class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={i:0};
  }

  increment = () => {
    this.setState({i: this.state.i+1});
  }


  render() {
    console.log('app::render');
    if (this.state.i % 2 === 0)
      return (
        <>
        <div>
          <div>
            <A key={42}/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.increment}>re-render</button>
        </>
      );
    else return (
      <>
      <div>
        <A key={42}/>
      </div>
      <button onClick={this.increment}>re-render</button>
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

Just to clarify, my code isn't trying to achieve anything except reproduce the issue, like I said, it's a SSCCE. Surely there are apps where they user can change the layout from a "preferences" menu so that a component ends up in a different place in the DOM depending on the user's preferences. I can't imagine its acceptable to lose the state in such a situation. What is the proper way to deal with this kind of situations?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the conditional rendering is returning two different tree structures where the path to `A` is different.

- `React.Fragment` > `div` > `div` > `A`
- `React.Fragment` > `div` > `A`

Imagine if we're mimicking React by using plain JS to do the mounting and unmounting manually, we will have to:

1. Store `<A/>` as a variable
2. Remove the inner `<div/>` (`<A/>` will automatically be removed as well)
3. Then append the previously stored `<A/>` into the outer `<div/>` (which actually is not a good approach either because this assumes `<A/>` will never need to update itself once it's mounted, even if the props change)

So long as there's a remove and append, it's quite equal to a React component being unmounted and then mounted again.

The code is a bit vague and I cannot tell what it's trying to achieve by having 2 `<div/>`s in the first condition and only 1 `<div/>` in the second. But perhaps you can use ternary operators to conditionally render just what you need and leave `<A/>` alone (and may be a bit of CSS to make the inner `<div/>` appear as if it is nested inside another `<div/>`). This way, `<A/>` will not unmount when `<App/>` changes state.

```
return (
  <>
    <div>
      <A />
      {condition ? // where `condition` is a boolean
        <div style={{
          position: 'absolute'
          // and may be other styles to achieve the visual trickery
        }}>
          {/* your content here */}
        </div>
        :
        null
      }
    </div>
    <button onClick={this.increment}>re-render</button>
  </>
)
```

By the way, they say 42 is the answer to everything, but I think not for this case. Setting the key to 42 won't help.

Comment: I added a clarification at the end of my question since you ask about what my code is trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating, but I guess that makes no difference in the answer I would give you.  You can try to use a ternary operator in the return statement. They usually come in handy in situations like this.